# Using DTO in Azure Mobile Service .NET throws target invocation exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure-mobile-services, dto

I use Azure Mobile Services .NET backend and we all know we have to use Entity Framework classes to map to the database creation/migration.
So I need to use DTOs to serialize only the properties I want, computed properties etc. I'm following the [Field Engineer example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Field-Engineer-501df99d). But Automapper gave me so much pain although I did everything as supposed to.

I have checked couple of others blog and site, some use Automapper, others not, for example [this one](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-leaderboard/). I feel more comfortable not using Automapper and create DTOs on the fly with Select() as I was doing it before when implementing Web API.

I reverted TableController class to Post, use the EntityDomainManager and I left the GetAllPosts method to the following.

```
public class PostController : TableController<Post>
{
    private MobileServiceContext _context;

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        _context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Post>(_context, Request, Services);
    }

    //[ExpandProperty("User")]
    // GET tables/Post
    public IQueryable<PostDto> GetAllPost()
    {
        return Query().Include("User").Select(x => new PostDto());
    }
}
```

I get the following error.

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.","exceptionType":"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException","stackTrace":"   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults(IQueryable queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The specified type member 'DatePosted' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.","exceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","stackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberAccessTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateSet(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ThenByTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateSet(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ThenByTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateSet(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection`1..ctor(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 pageSize)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)"}}
```

If I just convert it to the Entity Framework  class it works. You will notice that I don't fill any property, just for testing purposes.

I test locally with IIS Express.

Data objects and models.

```
    public class Post : EntityData
    {
        public DateTimeOffset DatePosted { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public PostType TypeOfPost { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual ICollection<PostPhotoUrl> PhotoUrls { get; set; }
    }

    public class PostDto
    {
        public PostDto()
        {
            PhotoUrls = new HashSet<PostPhotoUrlDto>();    
        }

        public DateTimeOffset DatePosted { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public int TypeOfPost { get; set; }

        public UserDto User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PostPhotoUrlDto> PhotoUrls { get; set; }
    }
```

Searching the internet couldn't find any other more clear tutorial how to use Azure Mobile Services and DTOs, though it shouldn't introduce such difficulty. If you have any resources are welcome.

I should mention that if I don't do the following the test website raises error when trying to test the endpoints.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

The exception snapshot:

[image: JsonMediaTypeFormatter Error]

I don't REALLY need to have DTOs for this project, but if I don't resolve what I don't understand right now it will come back and hunt me in the long run of this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Select() LINQ expression conflicts before the elements are fully loaded or the references are still unset.
I converted the method to a IEnumerable return type and eager loaded the data before transforming to DTOs.

```
        public IEnumerable<PostDto> GetAllPost()
        {
            return Query().Include("User").ToList().Select(x => new PostDto
            {
                DatePosted = x.DatePosted,
                StatusText = x.StatusText,
                TypeOfPost = (int)x.TypeOfPost,
                User = new UserDto
                {
                    Id = x.User.Id
                }  
            });
        }
```

After testing my service, it returned the following data I have inserted in my database.

```
[
    {
        "datePosted": "2015-04-27T04:05:38.843Z",
        "statusText": "Post Text",
        "typeOfPost": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": "a59d0f12-8bb1-448e-9c08-56f862b77ee4"
        },
        "photoUrls": []
    }
]
```

Should test with AutoMapper now to cover that it works with it too.

Only unknown point is why I need to set the `ReferenceLoopHandling` property to `Ignore` for the service to show properly JSON sample data.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but think the problem may be with this line of code

```
return Query().Include("User").Select(x => new PostDto());
```

if youre NOT using AutoMapper then you will need to manually parse the properties in your Select statement something like this

```
return Query().Include("User")
              .Select(x => new PostDto()
               {
                   DatePosted = x.DatePosted,
                   StatusText = x.StatusText,
                   TypeOfPost = x.TypeOfPost,
                   User = new UserDto
                          {
                              //Your propertoes here
                              //eg Id = x.User.Id etc
                           }  
               );
```